# How to get rid of this annoying W8123 warning in my IDE

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-xe

This is what happened.  We downloaded Quickreports 505, installed it, but had to revert to QR504.  Now we are getting

```
     [BCC32 Warning] W8123 Path 'C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0\Quickrep505C' not found - path ignored in option '-I'
```

This question has been asked on both Embarcadero, and quick report forums but all of their answers has been modify the cbproj file, which do not contain any references to quickreports.

I've tried removing all the references from the IDE but the warning still occurs.  Any suggestions on how to fix what should be a simple problem.

Sources:
https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=486503
http://forum.quickreport.co.uk/default.aspx?g=posts&t=1675

Using:
IDE: C++BuilderXE

Note I do not want to disable all warnings in the IDE, and I don't want to disable warnings in Code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had the same annoying problem. To fix this I had to delete all reference to the file in the EnvOptions.proj file. This file is located in the ...AppData\Roaming\Embarcadero\BDS\8.0\ folder.

Comment: I use XE2 and your workaround has fixed my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Unbelievable.  Thank you.  This worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

I got rid of this in my XE7 IDE directly via:

Tools > Options > Environment Options > C++ Options > Path and Directories.

There were invalid paths to libraries being referenced and showing up as warnings in the build. Select each of the `...` icons to explore the list of paths included, and select `Delete Invalid Paths` to remove unused paths.

[image]

Comment: Glad they finally fixed it.  But that did not work for me in XE1.

Comment: Is there an interface to manage the paths in XE1? That way you would not have to manually edit the EnvOptions.proj.

Answer (score 0):

To enhance and update prior answers, this is what I had to do...

From the menus: [Tools] [Options]

In the Dialog box: [Environment Options] [C++ Options] [Paths and Directories]

Now at the top on the right side in the drop down pick: [32-bit Windows]  (it started as Android)

The clear invalid paths in **both** tabs [Compiler] & [Classic Compiler]

Answer (score 0):

Remove Warning Message File Path Not Found

[BCC32 Warning] W8123 Path 'C:.....' not found - path ignored in option '-I'

- Version 10.4.2 Sydney
  ========
  In IDE Right Click on Executable

Options...

C++ Compiler->Directories and Conditionals

Include file search path > (Double click)

then click on

```
Value from "All configurations - All platforms"
```

Click on ... in right hand side in text edit box on right hand side

Click on down arrow beside button "Tasks"

Delete Invalid Paths

"Save"

Answer (score 0):

I have this project that I sometimes work at at the office and sometimes at home. And the paths of the external files are not the same on both computers, so I added them both in the folder lists.
Is there another way to supress these warnings without having to remove "invalid" paths from the folder lists?

Edit:

[image: Project Options]

I thought I found the answer, but this setting doesn't work